# Help regarding a proof about Dedekind finiteness

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory

I got this one as an exercise. If $F$ is Dedekind finite and $t \notin F$ then prove that $F \cup \{t\}$ is also Dedekind finite.

I gave this as an answer:

If $F\cup \{t\}$ is Dedekind infinite then there is $I\subset F\cup \{t\}$ that is equinumerous with $F\cup \{t\}$. If $t \notin I$ then $I \subset F$ and that would be false since $ I $ is equinumerous with $F\cup\{t\}$ and $F$ Dedekind finite. If $t \in I$, then there exist an $A \subset F$ so that $I = A\cup\{t\}$ and a bijection $f$ from $A\cup \{t\}$ to  $F\cup \{t\}$. If $f(t)=t$ then $f$ reduced to $A$ is also a bijection from $A$ to $F$ which is also false. If not there exist $u \in A$ and $v \in F$ so that $f(u)=t$ and $f(t)=v$. By setting $g(x)=f(x)$ if $x \in A \setminus \{u\}$  and $g(u)=v$ then $g$ is a bijection from $A$ to $F$ which is false since $F$ is Dedekind finite.

Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine. Could use some line breaks, though.

Comment: Thanks. You mean making it easier to read? Sorry about that I'm kinda new here, just recently learned how to write in MathJax

Comment: Looks good to me. Try this one : If F is Tarski finite then  it is Dedekind finite.(F is Tarski finite when every non-empty family of subsets of F has a subset-minimal member.)